# image url helper for sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, relative-path, helper

I'm looking for an image url helper for sinatra that allows me to do something similar to [staticmatic's](http://staticmatic.rubyforge.org/how_to_use.html#helpers), where I can shortcut to a relative path like so...

```
=img "me.jpg"
```

Can anybody point me in the direction to where this might be online, or where I could learn how to write one, or provide an example of one they have already written

Many thanks

Comment: Are you looking to replicate the whole of staticmatic, or just the part that builds the image tag from a filename? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want, you could use [sinatra-static-asset](http://github.com/wbzyl/sinatra-static-assets/) or a helper like this:

```
helpers do
  def img(name)
    "<img src='images/#{name}' alt='#{name}' />"
  end
end
```